# Installing python-based tools (httpie)

Tags: apt, python

On a fresh ubuntu, I wanted to install httpie, so I tried:

`sudo apt-get install httpie`

So that seems to have "worked" but I can't run `httpie`, it says command not found. When I look for it, it looks like all I have is the code for `httpie` here:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httpie
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/httpie
```

If I then CD to either of those folders, it's just the code for `httpie`.. Am I missing something obvious here? I've tried to close and restart the session.

BTW I'm using python 2.7, and the latest **Ubuntu (16.04.1)**

Thanks

Matt

Comment: which version of ubuntu/python are you using?

Comment: Sorry - updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the files installed by a package with `dpkg` command, like:

```
dpkg -L httpie
```

One can see that `/usr/bin/http` is the only binary installed by the package and hence, `http` might be the command you are loooking for

One can use `apt-file` if the package is not installed:

```
apt-file list httpie
```

Comment: Awesome stuff, I had no idea about the dpkg command :-) Thanks!